Display a formatted date of CurrentUICulture in EditorFor()
So I've been trying to "convert" a property of type DateTime to a formatted localized string to then display in a date input field.
My model's property:

[Display(Name = "StartingDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }


I've tried it with TextBoxFor() first, as you can easily pass your format as a parameter.
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartingDate, "{0:" + CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + "}")

Obviously it's a plain TextBox and not an Editor, which is not my goal.
I'v also tried to use EditorFor() / input of type "date".
Normal input tag:
<input type="date" value="@Model.StartingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)" name="StartingDate" />

EditorFor:
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartingDate, new { @value = Model.StartingDate.ToString("{0:d}", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) })

In both cases, the value is still displayed as "MM/dd/yyyy", though my CurrentUICulture would theoretically display it as "dd/MM/yyyy".
Any help is welcomed, if you need more code or some other information, I'll gladly provide it to you.

You're generating HTML/JS and sending it to a client where it will be evaluated and rendered. It should be displayed according to the Locale under which the user is running in their OS and browser, not the locale under which the server is running.

@AluanHaddad Aight thanks. Then my next question would be: how to change the Locale under which the user is running in their OS and browser? Or do you think I should use CurrentCulture instead of CurrentUICulture? Perhaps that would solve my issue.

You can't control the client's locale and you shouldn't depend on the server's locale (what if your server changes time zones or you move to the cloud. Your backend should store dates either as date types that  UTC or UTC offsets and not rely on the server locale for either representation or display.

@AluanHaddad Makes sense that I wouldn't want to change the server locale, but this is not about changing that, it's about displaying a datetime differently. So you're telling me it's not possible?
